# Removing specific layers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I have an application where I need to remove all layers, except for two specific ones.
My Goal is to be able to iterate over the layers and don't remove specified ones.

something like:

```
map.getLayers().forEach(layer => {
  if (layer has something) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
});
```

I found:

```
map.getLayers().forEach(layer => {
  if (layer && layer.get('name') === 'Marker') {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
});
```

but I don't know how to set the name of a layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set additional properties when you create a layer, for example

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
  name: 'Marker',
  source: vectorSource
})
```

You should avoid iterating a collection or array you are rearranging, for example

```
map.getLayers().forEach(layer => {
  map.removeLayer(layer);
});
```

will only remove every second layer.

If you want to remove more than one layer in a loop use slice to clone the array and iterate that

```
map.getLayers().getArray().slice().forEach(layer => {
  if (layer && layer.get('name') === 'Marker') {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
```

});